# applescript CURL with authentication fails

Tags: applescript, macos

QUESTION: i need a working method to be used in applescript to get the right source of the page, WITHOUT loading the page.

sample link: https://www.idealista.it/immobile/16679597/

result: wrong html, it talks about authentication.

INITIAL CODE (always present for all the tries below):

```
set MyUser to username@dom.com
set MyPass to password
set UrlOfPage to "https://www.idealista.it/immobile/16679597/"
```

TRIES (all of the tries below are given in this webpage https://ec.haxx.se/http-auth.html):

- works but need the page to be loaded in Safari

  ```
  tell front document of application "Safari" to set StrHtml to (get source) as string
  ```
- returns wrong html

  ```
  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " " & UrlOfPage)

  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --anyauth --user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " " & UrlOfPage)

  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --digest --user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " " & cellurl)

  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --negotiate --user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " " & cellurl)

  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --ntlm --user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " " & cellurl)
  ```
- doesn't work: unknown token

  ```
  set StrHtml to (do shell script "curl --proxy-anyauth --proxy-user " & MyUser & ":" & MyPass & " https://www.idealista.it/immobile/16679597/ \ --proxy https://proxy.idealista.it/immobile/16679597:80/")
  ```

could somebody help me now please?

Comment: Have you been able to get the right HTML using just `curl` in the Terminal? Adding AppleScript at this stage may be complicating the problem. Considering perfecting the `curl` command, then adding AppleScript to parse the result.

Comment: @GrahamMiln yeah, i tried but unfortunately it gives exactly the same results as using `curl` from shell script in applescript and the same results as using a simple `curl` without authentication. i'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @nohillside i'd like to grab the string just below "Statistiche", at the bottom of the page, right below the position on the map. The exact text i'd like to grab is "Annuncio aggiornato il 15 luglio" which in english it sounds something like "Updated on July, 15th".

Comment: You actually don't need to login, I get the same content without a login. Also, what actually happens is that the webserver recognizes your access as being from a script, and displays a dedicated page then (to verify this, set the User-Agent string to "curl" in Safari and reload).

Comment: Ok, so you got the same result, and i’m happy that i’m not the only one. Is there a way to solve this problem in legal terms and with a curl request?

Comment: @nohillside (previous comment)

Comment: I would start with the tools recommended in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

## Dedicated Tools

Given the problems encountered with `curl` and AppleScript, consider using an alternative dedicated tool such as [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). See [How To Scrape Web Pages with Beautiful Soup and Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3) for a comprehensive introduction.

Alternatively, there are numerous tools other that can help, see [Web scraping software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Software) on Wikipedia. Many of these tools are free, open-source, and can be called from the command line.

I have previously used [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Web-Scraper/lib/Web/Scraper.pm) for extracting [property listings](https://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2010/03/06/property-hunting-in-lyon-web-scraper-and-tbody-tags/).

Comment: Does it have a cost? Does it grab part of html and give it to applescript? Does it work on High Sierra OS X?

Comment: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is open source and free. Many of the other tools are also free and can be used from the command line and thus interacted with using AppleScript.